# Twitter data & python - TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

Tags: python, pandas

I wrote a function to remove hashtags from tweets in a Twitter dataset. I'm trying to run it on the tweets in a pandas dataframe using the map function. But I keep getting this error: "TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object"

I've googled the error message and looked at quite a few similar issues here, but nothing has worked so far. Do I need to convert the tweet object into a different type?

```
def remove_hashtags(tweet):
    no_hashtags = []
    if len(re.findall("(#[^#\s]+)", tweet)) > 0:
        tweet = re.sub("(#[^#\s]+)", "", tweet)
    no_hashtags.append(tweet)
    return no_hashtags[0]
```

```
text_all_removed = text_no_links.map(remove_hashtags)
```

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-143-84c94835f61a> in <module>
----> 1 text_all_removed = text_no_links.map(remove_hashtags)

~/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py in map(self, arg, na_action)
   3380         """
   3381         new_values = super(Series, self)._map_values(
-> 3382             arg, na_action=na_action)
   3383         return self._constructor(new_values,
   3384                                  index=self.index).__finalize__(self)

~/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/base.py in _map_values(self, mapper, na_action)
   1216 
   1217         # mapper is a function
-> 1218         new_values = map_f(values, mapper)
   1219 
   1220         return new_values

pandas/_libs/lib.pyx in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer()

<ipython-input-142-5e6df146cb08> in remove_hashtags(tweet)
      3 def remove_hashtags(tweet):
      4     no_hashtags = []
----> 5     if len(re.findall("(#[^#\s]+)", tweet)) > 0:
      6         tweet = re.sub("(#[^#\s]+)", "", tweet)
      7     no_hashtags.append(tweet)

~/venv/lib64/python3.6/re.py in findall(pattern, string, flags)
    220 
    221     Empty matches are included in the result."""
--> 222     return _compile(pattern, flags).findall(string)
    223 
    224 def finditer(pattern, string, flags=0):

TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

output of text_no_links.head()

```
0    [ #bbcqt Remoaners on about post Brexit racial...
1    [@sarahwollaston Shut up, you like all remoane...
2    [ what have the Brextremists ever done for us ...
3                     [ Remoaner in bizarre outburst ]
4    [ Anyone who disagrees with brexit is called n...
Name: text, dtype: object
```

Comment: This error is telling you that tweet is not a string.  Maybe try type(text_no_links) and see what type of object you are actually sending to the function. Try that and let us know what the result is.

Comment: ok - it's showing as pandas.core.series.Series - do I need to convert that into a string?

Comment: It makes sense that it's a series, the map should apply to each item in the series.  print(text_no_links) to see if the contents of your series are actually strings.  Then try type(text_no_links[0]) to see the type of object your actual item is.  It should be string.

Comment: hmm, it's a list

Comment: if you can post the output of text_no_links.head() as an update to your question it will help.

Comment: hey @Chris - I just posted it

Comment: Try this: tweet = re.sub("(#[^#\s]+)", "", tweet[0])